# access matrix by rownames and colnames, and return zero if not available

Tags: r, matrix, zero

I have a matrix with rownames and colnames as:

```
a = matrix(1:4,2,2)
dimnames(a) = list(c("x","y"),c("x","y"))
```

I can have access to matrix elements by rownames and colnames, for example,

```
a["x","y"]
```

When I type a["x","z"], it gives me an error "Error in a["x", "z"] : subscript out of bounds", which should be.

My question is how can I get zero instead of that error. More precisely, when I type wrong rownames or colnames that are not in rownames(a) or colnames(a), it returns a fixed value such as zero. For example, zero for a["x","z"], a["z","t"], ... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in `tryCatch`.  No packages are used:

```
tryCatch(a["x", "y"], error = function(e) 0)
## [1] 3

tryCatch(a["x", "w"], error = function(e) 0)
## [1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap with a `tryCatch` or `possibly` from `purrr` to make this happen

```
library(purrr)
f1 <- possibly(function(mat, indx1, indx2) mat[indx1, indx2], otherwise = 0)
f1(a, 'x', 'z')
#[1] 0

f1(a, 'x', 'y')
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `match` to make sure an `NA` is returned instead:

```
a[match("x",rownames(a)), match("y",colnames(a))]
#[1] 3

a[match("x",rownames(a)), match("z",colnames(a))]
#[1] NA
```